# Automaton equivalent of the π calculus?

Tags: automata, concurrency, machine-models, pi-calculus

If Turing Machines are the automata equivalent of the $\lambda$ calculus, what is the automaton equivalent of the $\pi$ calculus? I suppose it would be some class of automata that resembled a Turing Machine, but with support for communication channels or signals of some type, but I'm not sure, and would appreciate some direction.

Comment: I think (labelled) transition systems are commonly thought of as equivalent. Classic automata/language theory does not really apply since we don't build acceptors here.

Comment: @Raphael, would you please elaborate on your second sentence?

Comment: @BlueBomber Would you be able to elaborate your question a little bit? In what sense are TMs the "automata equivalent of the $\lambda$-calculus"? Expressive power? Then $\pi$-calculus is the same as $\lambda$-calculus and TMs. Automata with channels for interaction are process calculi.

Comment: @Martin Berger, we learn in unversity that the lambda calculus and Turing machines are equivalent with respect to computing power, which is probably what you refer to by expressive power, but it isn't what I mean. As far as I can tell, there is no way in either the lambda calculus or Turing machines to express "wait for signal on channel c before continuing". The pi calculus has that, and so do modern computers (and I understand that it doesn't necessarily increase the power/expressiveness of the system in a formal sense).

Comment: Have you checked out 'communicating automata'? I think that it may be what you are looking for. A reference that treats this topic is mentioned [here](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/14506/).

Comment: @BlueBomber As I pointed out in my answer to [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-the-lambda-calculus-or-turing-machines-model-signals-callbacks-sleep-wait?rq=1) question, Turing machines can express waiting for a channel, but the modelling tends to be inconvenient, e.g. you need to encode channels, signals etc as certain strings that you put on tape. If you want more convenience, you have to go to calculi that models the features you want explicitly. There are many, e.g. interacting TMs, CCS, CSP and $\pi$ calculi.

Comment: @MartinBerger, thank you for the reference; I followed it and read the info there. I still don't see how a TM can perform a wait; the only operations a TM can perform (whatever definition of the many equivalent TM definitions you may choose), involve action: Moving the head, reading a character, and/or changing a character. It seems to me that the best we can do in any encoding of channels is the TM form of busy waiting, which is not an acceptable model for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @BlueBomber whoever is teaching you computation is not doing a great job ;-) The key point, as I said, is encoding. Let's take $\pi$-calculus. It has only a countable number of processes, and we can find a simple, injective encoding $enc(P)$ from $\pi$-calculus processes to $\{0, 1\}^*$, i.e. binary strings, together with an inverse decoding $dec(.)$. We can also write a Turing machine $M$ that
acts as a $\pi$-calculus interpreter, meaning that $M(enc(P)) =
enc(Q)$ exactly when $P \rightarrow Q$ in the $\pi$-calculus. Bingo,
you have signals, channels and the like. (Continued below.)

Comment: (Continued from above.) Is this convenient to work
with in practise? No. Does it give you all the power of process
calculi in the language of Turing machines? Yes. These kinds of encodings form the heart of the Church-Turing thesis. See also [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/applicability-of-church-turing-thesis-to-interactive-models-of-computation/12429#12429) discussion.

Comment: @MartinBerger, thank you for your comment, it was mostly very helpful. Comments like "whoever is teaching you computation is not doing a great job", on the other hand, are not helpful at all, even with winky faces.

Comment: [$\pi$ calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus), wikipedia

Answer (score -1):

The question doesnt make too much sense because the [$\pi$-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus#Turing_completeness) was [proven Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus#Turing_completeness), or in other words equivalent to a Turing machine ever since its inception by Milner in 1992. There is [a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I read in the linked article that there is an embedding of the Lambda calculus into Pi calculus. The other direction is not mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Turing Machines are to the λ-calculus as Chemical Abstract Machines are to the π-calculus.

Basically, a Chemical Abstract Machine is modeled as a set of molecules that, on each process step, some subset of the molecules react, are consumed by the reaction, and produce new molecules.

Comment: Could you give us some more details?  A link to a paper or at least a paper reference (author/paper-name/journal/date)?  It would be most helpful if you could tell us a little bit about how the features of Chemical Abstract Machines relate to the features of the $\pi$-calculus.

Comment: I don't see either how this analogy works. While $\pi$-calculus has a natural CHAM formulation, the connection between TMs and $\lambda$-calculus is complicated and torturous.

Comment: @WanderingLogic The founding paper for the CHAM is [The Chemical Abstract Machine](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~fvalenci/papers/cham.pdf) by G. Berry and G. Boudol. IIRC Milner used the CHAM for the first time in [Functions as Processes](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00075405/en/) to explain the $\pi$-calculus.